# Spell checking using fastText model?

Tags: python, fasttext

So I'm using `fastText` from its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python) and wondering if it has build-in spell checking command.

If yes, how do I use them? and can I get full documentation of `fastText` because as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206557/how-to-find-similar-words-with-fasttext) answer from [Kalana Geesara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10489503/kalana-geesara), I could use `model.get_nearest_neighbor` (and it worked) while I can't find it anywhere (even in the repo readme).

If no, is there any way for me to do spell checking with the model provided?

I am using english model provided [here](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html) and code it without `Gensim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using [Peter Norvig's Spell Correction Algorithm](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) and load it with fastText models.

But I've to install it with `Gensim` since I only found a [tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/cpmpml/spell-checker-using-word2vec/input) about it.